# MYSQL: GROUP BY on all values except 0 and null?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple SQL Query:

```
  SELECT tid, 
         COUNT(*) AS bpn
    FROM mark_list 
   WHERE userid = $userid 
GROUP BY tid
```

Now the column `tid` is basically a category list associated with each entry.  The categories are unique numeric values.

What I am trying to do is get an overall count of how many records there as per `userid`, but I only want to count an entire category one time (meaning if category 3 has 10000 records, it should only receive a count of 1).

The caveat is that sometimes the category is listed as null or sometimes a 0.  If the item has either a 0 or a null, it has no category and I want them counted as their own separate entities and not lumped into a single large category.

Comment: Instead of `tid, COUNT(*)` try something like `COUNT(DISTINCT tid)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wheeee!

```
SELECT SUM(`tid` IS NULL) AS `total_null`,
       SUM(`tid` = 0) AS `total_zero`, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT `tid`) AS `other`
  FROM `mark_list`
 WHERE `user_id` = $userid
```

Edit: note that if total_zero is greater than 0, you will have to subtract one from the "other" result (because tid=0 will get counted in that column)

Comment: Don't need backticks (`) for columns/tables that are not MySQL reserved words

Comment: Don't need 'em, but using them around all identifiers is best practice!

Comment: No, always using backticks to hide errors is not a best practice.  They exist to escape words that you should **not** be using...

Comment: That is an opinion, and one I do not hold to myself.  The list of reserved words is version-specific.  Best practice is NOT to memorize the list of reserved words for a given version, but to use backticks around all identifiers.

Comment: Now, if only MySQL would have adopted standard SQL Syntax .. if you use ANSI compatibility then it's the correct `"identifier"` syntax. Good heavens.

Comment: @tehshrike You sir, kick ass.  Works perfectly!

Comment: Hah, I wonder if my downvote was a result of this backtick business.  In any case, I'm with pst... some ANSI compliance in this area would have been nice.

Answer (score 2):

You can alter the query to not take into account those particular values (via the WHERE clause), and then perhaps run a separate query that ONLY takes into account those values.

There may be a way to combine it into only one query, but this way should work, too.